# What is the purpose of jsfiddle-integration-babel.js?

Tags: reactjs, jsfiddle

What is the purpose of

```
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js">
</script>
```

in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/) found on Facebook's React tutorial?

The content of `jsfiddle-integration-babel.js` is

```
(function() {
  var tag = document.querySelector(
    'script[type="application/javascript;version=1.7"]'
  );
  if (!tag || tag.textContent.indexOf('window.onload=function(){') !== -1) {
    alert('Bad JSFiddle configuration, please fork the original React JSFiddle');
  }
  tag.setAttribute('type', 'text/babel');
  tag.textContent = tag.textContent.replace(/^\/\/<!\[CDATA\[/, '');
})();
```

Looks like `tag` tracks a script and removes certain comments from it. But why?

Comment: It changes `<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7">` to `<script 'text/babel'>` so that babel knows which code to transpile (it makes jsx in react work)

Comment: @azium Why don't they serve scripts with the right `type` in the first place?

Comment: Presumably this is to make the jsfiddle environment babel friendly, which may imply overriding existing jsfiddle code

Comment: @azium You're right. If your comment was an answer, I would have accepted it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting azium from the comments

> Presumably this is to make the jsfiddle environment babel friendly,
>   which may imply overriding existing jsfiddle code